# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate return old AND new values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have update query like this

```
Balances.findOneAndupdate({_id:  }, {$inc: {balance: 10}}, { new: true })
```

In post middleware i've got

```
schema.post('findOneAndUpdate', function (result) {
  result === updated document
})
```

How can i get old and new(both of them) values (for logging) without multiple queries ?
Thanks.

Comment: you can either get old value or new, not both https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone need, i solve it with transactions.

```
const session = await dbInstance.startSession()
await session.startTransaction()
query ...
query ...
await session.commitTransaction()
session.endSession()
```